# Why my django form is invalid even though I am filling all the required parameters?

Tags: python, html, django

I am making a very simple web application where users encounter a form in which they can select a origin,destination (both are airports) and a date for their travel.

I only have one form in forms.py:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm,DateField,ChoiceField
from .models import Flight
from django.forms.widgets import SelectDateWidget,TextInput
from datetime import datetime
from .skyscanner import list_airports

airports = list_airports()


class FlightForm(ModelForm):
    origin = ChoiceField(required=True, choices = airports)
    destination = ChoiceField(required=True, choices = airports)

    class Meta:
        model = Flight
        fields = ['origin', 'destination', 'date']
        widgets = {
            'date': SelectDateWidget(years=[2021,2022]),
        }
```

Where I declaratively define `'origin'` and `'destination'` while `'date'` is coming from Flight model but represented as `SelectDateWidget`. Here is my models.py :

```
from decimal import Decimal
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from . import fields


class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Airport(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.city} ({self.code})"

class Flight(models.Model):
    origin = models.ForeignKey(Airport, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="departures")
    destination = models.ForeignKey(Airport, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="arrivals")
    price = fields.DecimalRangeField(min_value=Decimal(
        '0.00'), decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    date = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'From {self.origin} to {self.destination} at {self.date}'
```

And the index view:

```
    def index(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            origin=Airport.objects.get(code=request.POST['origin'])
            destination=Airport.objects.get(code=request.POST['destination'])
           form = FlightForm({'origin': origin, 
     'destination': destination,
     'date': f"{request.POST.get('date_year')}-{request.POST.get('date_month')}-{request.POST.get('date_day')}"})
            if form.is_valid():
                flight={}
                flight['origin'] = form.cleaned_data['origin']
                flight['destination'] = form.cleaned_data['destination']
                flight['date'] = form.cleaned_data['date']
          
                return render(request, "flights/search_results.html",{
            "flight": flight
        })
        else:
       
            form = FlightForm()
            return render(request, "flights/index.html", {'form': form})
```

My index.html:

```
  <form action="{% url 'flights:index' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="origin">Origin</label>
                    {{ form.origin|addclass:'form-control' }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="destination">Destination</label>
                    {{ form.destination|addclass:'form-control' }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md">
                <label for="Date">Date</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-md">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            {{ form.date|addclass:'col-md form-control' }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Search">
</div>
</form>
```

If the `request.method` is not `'POST'` users see `index.html` as it should be but when a form is submitted form does not pass `is_valid` check.

Comment: replace date=request.POST['date] to date=request.POST.getlist('date[]') then print to check what you get

Comment: @harshilsuthar an empty list ..

Comment: if you directly try to get date using request.POST['date'] then if value is null then return error so always use request.POST.get('date') if no data found then it will return none.

Comment: if form is not valid, render the template with that invalid form, so that user can see the error & also their input values will be preserved